# Migration not found event after running composer dump-autoload

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, migration, laravel-artisan

I receive this error after running `php artisan migrate:rollback`:

> Migration not found: 2018_04_19_054123_create_business_users_table

I ran these commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

But I still receive the error. Can I delete such cache manually? and from where?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For rollback migration in Laravel you need to install `dbal` library:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

After that migration rollback will be done.